# Youtube Live API Error in creating a live Broadcast with isDefaultBroadcast=True

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'am using python to create a broadcast with api youtube streaming.
Every day I want to create a schedule video and stream it with the same url access.
So in my code I add isDefaultBroadcast=True

```
# Create a liveBroadcast resource and set its title, scheduled start time,
# scheduled end time, and privacy status.
def insert_broadcast(youtube, options):
  insert_broadcast_response = youtube.liveBroadcasts().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        title=options.broadcast_title,
        isDefaultBroadcast=True,
        scheduledStartTime=options.start_time,
        scheduledEndTime=options.end_time
      ),
      status=dict(
        privacyStatus=options.privacy_status
      )
    )
  ).execute()
```

But i got an error 403

```
 An HTTP error 403 occurred:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "liveBroadcastBindingNotAllowed",
    "message": "The binding is not allowed"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The binding is not allowed"
 }
}
```

I have add isDefaultStream fot the liveStream part and no problem with it.

Any idea what's going wrong ?